# RxJava2 toList() never emits

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

So I have following Disposable which doesn't work. I am using Room to get all rows from a table as a list, map each of them to something and create a list and then it doesn't continue from there.

```
storedSuggestionDao
    .getSuggestionsOrderByType() //Flowable
    .doOnNext(storedSuggestions -> Timber.e("storedSuggestions: " + storedSuggestions)) //this work
    .flatMapIterable(storedSuggestions -> storedSuggestions)
    .map(Selection::create) ))
    .doOnNext(selection -> Timber.e("Selection: " + selection)) // works
    .toList()
    .toObservable() // nothing works after this...
    .doOnNext(selections -> Timber.d("selections: " + selections))
    .map(SuggestionUiModel::create)
    .doOnNext(suggestionUiModel -> Timber.d("suggestionUiModel: " + suggestionUiModel))
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: why do you need to use `.toObservable()` ?

Comment: Because this is inside another stream which gets the string etc.. from the ui and check if it is required to get stored suggestions or hit the network. But even I don't do toObservable() it still doesn't emit after toList(). It is a Single at that point so it should return something inside onSuccess()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These types of data sources from 3rd parties are usually infinite sources but `toList()` requires a finite source. I guess you wanted to process that collection of `storedSuggestions` and keep it together. You can achieve this via an inner transformation:

```
storedSuggestionDao
.getSuggestionsOrderByType() //Flowable
.doOnNext(storedSuggestions -> Timber.e("storedSuggestions: " + storedSuggestions)) //this work
// -------------------------------------
.flatMapSingle(storedSuggestions -> 
    Flowable.fromIterable(storedSuggestions)
    .map(Selection::create)
    .doOnNext(selection -> Timber.e("Selection: " + selection))
    .toList()
)
// -------------------------------------
.doOnNext(selections -> Timber.d("selections: " + selections))
.map(SuggestionUiModel::create)
.doOnNext(suggestionUiModel -> Timber.d("suggestionUiModel: " + suggestionUiModel))
.subscribe();
```

Comment: So this works :) Room provided an infinite stream of data (so when changes happens in the database, you can get them) and this caused this issue as I am "USED TO" of finite streams (i.e. network calls etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case you don't need to call .toObserable()

It should be like this

```
storedSuggestionDao
.getSuggestionsOrderByType() //Flowable
.doOnNext(storedSuggestions -> Timber.e("storedSuggestions: " + storedSuggestions)) //this work
.flatMapIterable(storedSuggestions -> storedSuggestions)
.map(Selection::create) ))
.doOnNext(selection -> Timber.e("Selection: " + selection)) // works
.toList() // you don't have to call .toObserable()
.map(SuggestionUiModel::create)
.subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is 
`storedSuggestionDao.getSuggestionsOrderByType() //Flowable`

is a hot stream. 
`toList` still waits for upstream to complete