# Perform request for each DB entry

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java, android-room

I'm trying to integrate an existing working code that uses Retrofit for API requests with SQLite Room in Android.

```kotlin
val apiInterface = ApiInterface.create()
val requests = ArrayList<Observable<Business>>()
requests.addAll(DB.getAllBusinessEntry().map { // fun getAllBusinessEntry(): List<BusinessEntry>
    apiInterface.getBusiness(it.major, it.minor)
})
Observable.zip(requests)
{ objects ->
     val businesses = ArrayList<Business>()
     objects.forEach { businesses.add(it as Business) }
     return@zip businesses
}
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe {
    businessAdapter.updateElements(it)
}
```

`BusinessEntry` is a data class containing primary keys (`major` and `minor`) that allow to perform an API request to fetch business details (stored in `Business`).
`DB.getAllBusinessEntry()` is a function that uses a DB Helper class as documented in the Android documentation to access the SQLite database internal to the application.

I'd like to migrate this code to Room and rely on RxJava functionalities, but I don't know how to transform every `BusinessEntry` in an `ApiInterface` call.

Following is the `BusinessDao` interface

```kotlin
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Query
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable

@Dao
interface BusinessDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Entry")
    fun getAll(): Observable<List<Entry>>
}
```

I'm using Room 2.3.0-alpha02

---

**EDIT**: with suggestions from comments I've achieved this which still doesn't work because, in the final `subscribe` call `businessList` is of type `List<Observable<Business>!>!` while it should be `List<Business>`

```kotlin
swipeRefreshLayout?.isRefreshing = true
val apiInterface = ApiInterface.create()

businessDB.businessDao().getAll()
    .flatMapSingle { entries ->
        Observable.fromIterable(entries)
            .map { apiInterface.getBusiness(it.major, it.minor) }
            .toList()
    }
    .map { it.filter { true } }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe { businessList ->
        swipeRefreshLayout?.isRefreshing = false
        businessAdapter.updateElements(businessList) // <-- type error here
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not specialist in RxJava, but I can suggest to try this:

```
roomDb.businessDao().getAll()
    .flatMap { entryList -> Observable.fromIterable(entryList) }
    .flatMap { entry -> apiInterface.getBusiness(entry.major, entry.minor) }
    .toList()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe { businessList -> businessAdapter.updateElements(businessList) }
```

where `roomDb` - is an instance of Room database object and `roomDb.businessDao()` gives you an instance of autogenerated class that implements `BusinessDao` interface (of course, if you've added method `businessDao()` to Room database class). You can read in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) more about that.

**UPDATE**

There was a problem with `toList()` operator used above, since Room's Observable creates kinda infinite stream that waits for constant updates of data and it never completes. Solution to that found at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47329023/12718414).

```
businessDB.businessDao().getAll()
    .flatMapSingle { entries ->
        Observable.fromIterable(entries)
            .flatMap { apiInterface.getBusiness(it.major, it.minor) }
            .toList()
    }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe { businessList ->
        swipeRefreshLayout?.isRefreshing = false
        businessAdapter.updateElements(businessList)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. The snippet you provided seems correct, but it never gets to the `updateElements` call, apparently. I can see requests (not empty) hitting the backend, but then nothing: no breakpoints nor logging. Any suggestion?

Comment: What I found that problem is might be in `toList()` operator, since Room's Observable creates kinda infinite stream that waits for constant updates of data and it never completes. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data#column-indexing) is decision of one of the similar problem, try it.

Comment: I've tried putting indices, but it doesn't work. I believe a possible solution could be replacing the return type in the Dao from `Observable` to `Single`/`Maybe` but I really have too little experience for this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've put wrong link above: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47329023/12718414). Indices have nothing with the problem of course

Comment: It still doesn't work, but it may be close to correctess. I've also added a `.filter {true}` because otherwise it would have been a `(Mutable)List<Observable<Business>!>!`. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: try to change in `.map { apiInterface.getBusiness(it.major, it.minor) }` to `flatMap`

Comment: It works, even without the `.filter { true }` thing, thank you very much. Feel free to update the answer and I will accept it (I'm not sure if an answer can be edited after it is accepted).

Comment: Glad it was helpful